# Can not close popup window using Modal in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have opened an popup window in Joomla 1.5 using modal.js. It's a SqueezeBox. I'm tried call close this popup on popup content but can't.

In Chrome it get an message

> Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read property '`x`' of `undefined`

Comment: some code would be nice. Are you trying to put a close link inside the modal window?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout('closeme();', 5000);
    function closeme()
    {
        parent.SqueezeBox.close();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will helps you...

Answer (score 1):

I used Joomla 2.5 modal for open Virtuemart 2 "ask about product". And here is my code (for my `<button>` attribute) to close modal window:

```
onclick="parent.document.getElementById('sbox-btn-close').click();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Squeezebox attaches a close() method to the div container with id 'sbox-window'. From your modal content find this element and execute close().

If using default modal method (Modal content received through ajax and injected directly into the DOM).

document.getElementById('sbox-window').close();

If modal is in a iframe

window.parent.document.getElementById('sbox-window').close();

Answer (score 0):

Just call  `SqueezeBox.close();` while operating with modals in Joomla backend.